# How can I share images on a S3 bucket from a Flutter Web app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

On the mobile versions of the app I am using the [esys flutter share package](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share)

This is the snippet that I am using:

```
() async {
                    var request = await HttpClient()
                        .getUrl(Uri.parse(product.imageUrl));
                    var response = await request.close();
                    Uint8List bytes =
                        await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
                    await Share.file(
                        'Text to show?', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',
                        text: '${product.name}\nSolo por $finalPrice');
                  }
```

Unfortunately this package doesn't support Web platform.

There is a package called [share plus 2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/versions/2.0.0)

On the example they say that one can share files in the following way:

```
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image.jpg'], text: 'Great picture');
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image1.jpg', '${directory.path}/image2.jpg']);
```

However, in my case the file is on S3. I need to download it to some app folder. Because my app is Web I don't know how to download the pictures and stored in a folder of the app. Is this possible? Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

keep downloaded file in a variable and then push it where you need it.